# Laravel Sortby Filter Search Products by Select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Whats the best way to build an Product Search Filter with an `<select>`?

My Route:

```
Route::any ( '/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    if($q != ""){
    $products = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->paginate (200)->setPath ( '' );
    $pagination = $products->appends ( array (
                'q' => Input::get ( 'q' ) 
        ) );



    if (count ( $products ) > 0)
        return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
    }
        return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'No Products!' );
} );
```

Now i want add an Drop down Filter with  `<select>` to Search Page like:

```
<select name="sortby">

  <option value="newproducts">New Products</option>

  <option value="cheapprice">Cheapest Price</option>

</select>
```

Can i do it in my Route like:

```
if (select( ..newproducts... ) > 0)
    return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
}
```

Thanks for some tips:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can add it there, but not with a conditional. You already pass a query parameter to search, just give the select a name and send that along too. You would use `->orderBy(...)` on you collection you get when searching for $q.

```
// from your html
<select name="sortby">

// in your controller/route
$products->orderBy(request->get('sortBy'))

// new products
If (request->get('sortBy') === 'newproducts')
    $products->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

// cheap price
If (request->get('sortBy') === 'cheapprice')
    $products->orderBy('price', 'asc');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Comment: No you'd chain an orderBy method call on your results of searching for $q. That would give you a sorted collection of only the results you found. If no $q is given then it would sort all the products by your select option.

Comment: And how can i use for example "cheapprice" after sortBy?

Comment: Edited my answer with examples. I see what you meant with the if select now, added it in too.

Comment: Thanks friend,you helped me a lot:)